# Docker alpine + oracle java: cannot find java

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I've been trying to create an alpine-based docker image with Oracle Java (rather than openjdk). I have been specifically asked to create our own image here.

This is the Dockerfile I've come up with:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add --no-cache curl wget

RUN mkdir /opt/ && \
    wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"\
    http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
    rm jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_131 /opt/jdk

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/jdk/bin

RUN echo $JAVA_HOME && \
    echo $PATH

RUN which java
RUN java -version
```

There are some unnecessary commands (like echoing the JAVA_HOME dir) which were added to help with debugging, but now I'm stuck: `RUN which java` returns `/opt/jdk/bin/java` as expected, but `RUN java -version` returns `/bin/sh: java: not found`.

I've tried a few things, including symlinking the executable(s) into /usr/bin, to no avail.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Final output from docker is:
`The command '/bin/sh -c java -version' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Final edit:

Thanks to diginoise for putting me on to MUSL vs libc. I found adding the following to my Dockerfile allowed me to build a working image:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates && \
wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/master/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-2.25-r0.apk && \
apk add glibc-2.25-r0.apk
```

Found at: https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc

Comment: what do you get from echo $JAVA_HOME and $PATH?

Comment: JAVA_HOME: `/opt/jdk`
PATH: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/jdk/bin`

Comment: can you try `RUN echo "$(java -version)"` ?

Comment: I get the same output using echo "$(java -version)"

Comment: You assume where Java is going to reside... Can you start interactive session with your container and verify where exactly Java is

Comment: have you tried then the `RUN /opt/jdk/bin/java -version`?

Comment: @Edwin I get the same output with the fully qualified path!
@diginoise I can't start an interactive session without some kind of entrypoint (a java server app, for instance). However, using `RUN ls -l /opt/jdk/bin` etc. shows what you'd expect (the executables are def. in that location).

Comment: check this article: https://runnable.com/docker/java/dockerize-your-java-application, it has some steps that can apply to your dockerfile too. Worth trying.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I added the lines as @phanteh suggested and I mgetting this error: wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: @MehmedB It looks like those lines are out of date. The github page I linked to is now referencing: glibc-2.30-r0.apk

Comment: The issue was that I was missing GLibC. Once that was on the system it all ran fine. See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### You cannot achieve what you want

Alpine Linux uses MUSL as a Standard C library.

Oracle's Java for linux depends on GNU Standard C library (gclib).

[Here is a bit more detailed info and official stance from Oracle on the topic](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/official-docker-image-for-oracle-java-and-the-openjdk-roadmap-for-containers)

> the JDK source code has not yet been ported to Alpine Linux, or more specifically, the musl C library. That is, it turns out that the thing about Alpine Linux that sticks out/is different from a JDK source code perspective is the C library.

### The solution

If you looking for small Java Docker images, [use OpenJDK ones](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/tree/master/repos/openjdk/remote).

`openjdk:11-jre-slim` image is only **77MB**.

---

### If you insist, on your head be it...

There is theoretical way, [but it is not as trivial as you think](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs).

You can find many examples of Alpine images running with OracleJDK like [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/%7E/dockerfile/) or see [expert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226895/expert)'s answer to this question as well.
They add the missing Standard GNU C library.

#### Be warned however...

All of these solutions ***could be in breach*** of Oracle's license agreement stating that the license is **non-transferable**, and the distributable is **non-modifiable**.
In the `Dockerfile`s you will find however:

```
Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
```

and many entries similar to

```
rm -rf ${JAVA_HOME}/*src.zip
```

For further details about legality of prepackaged Oracle's **JRE** or **JDK** Docker images [see this article](https://www.overops.com/blog/running-java-on-docker-youre-breaking-the-law/).

Comment: .. because the exit code he sees comes from a crashing Java process that misses the aforementioned dependencies

Comment: You can find examples of Alpine images running with OracleJDK [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8/~/dockerfile/) and [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/~/dockerfile/). Its basically always about adding the missing GNU C library.

Comment: @LazerBass please edit my answer to add the 2 docker alpine images which have glibC and I will happily approve!

Comment: From what I'm seeing around the internet this does not to be a correct answer.
https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/minimal-java-docker-containers/

Comment: @b01 please find details in the update to my answer. Adding Oracle's java to docker image **could** be in breach of their licensing agreement.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that works finally. All is needed is just the [GlibC](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc); huge thanks to [S. Gerrand](https://github.com/sgerrand), this is such a big help.

Here's how to get the old JDK 8 running in Alpine 1.13:

```
FROM alpine:3.13

RUN apk --no-progress --purge --no-cache upgrade \
&& apk --no-progress --purge --no-cache add --upgrade \
    curl \
    wget \
    openssh \
&& apk --no-progress --purge --no-cache upgrade \
&& rm -vrf /var/cache/apk/* \
&& curl --version

# Install vanilla GLibC: https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc
RUN curl -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
&& curl -LO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.32-r0/glibc-2.32-r0.apk \
&& apk add glibc-2.32-r0.apk

RUN wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
        http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  && tar xvf jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt \
  && rm jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_131 /opt/jdk

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/jdk/bin

RUN echo $JAVA_HOME && \
    echo $PATH

RUN which java
RUN java -version

ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]

# To test run: docker run -t khalifahks/alpine-java -version
# docker export <container-id> | docker import - khalifahks/alpine-java:exported
# quick interative termnal: docker run -it --entrypoint=sh khalifahks/alpine-java sh
```

Comment: barring any licensing issues, this works. The image size was 408MB. Not ideal. but not too bad either. They may be some cleanup that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs fresh version of JDK I maintain Alpine Oracle JDK images https://hub.docker.com/r/expert/docker-java-minimal

Sources
https://github.com/unoexperto/docker-java-minimal/

Comment: Please find my updated answer and the discussion about legality of packaging Oracle's binaries.

Answer (score -1):

im trying to run my own docker java app, and i have a problem, when i add

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/jdk/bin
```

to my dockerfile, im getting

```
/bin/sh: ENV: not found
```

and i have no idea how to install ENV, or how to make it work...