# Jenkins Blue Ocean: Maven doesn't see Java

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm getting the error "/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin/java: not found:" even though the path exists:

```
   

[edi-debatcher_master-LNI22Y2C5V3VECCBCFPVB3ZUWJJNMLK6LIFEQ6V3OYH52T74NU3A@2] Running shell script
+ echo PATH = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
PATH = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
+ echo M2_HOME = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3
M2_HOME = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3
+ mvn -version
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.3/bin/mvn: exec: line 199: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8/bin/java: not found
```

I am using the Jenkins Blue Ocean feature, GitHub Jenkinsfile. I have "jdk8" and "Maven 3.5.3" defined in Global Tool Configuration, "autoinstall" checked.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
          steps {
            sh '''
               echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
               echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
               mvn --version 
               '''
          }
        }
        stage('Build') {
          steps {
            sh 'mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true install'
          }
          post {
            success {
              junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.5.3'
        jdk 'jdk8'
      }
      post {
        always {
        deleteDir()
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that are you checking machine with jenkins slave that executes your job (not other slave or master)?

Comment: I found a workaround: instead of the Oracle auto-install JDK I used the default OpenJDK version 8 already installed: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk ...it could be that there is something wrong with the Oracle JDK autoinstall integration.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120476/jenkins-config-jdk-for-project-and-maven-build-always-get-error/

Answer (score 2):

You are running a wrong version of the file (here java) for the system.

**Problem:** 
The file is there and can not be executed. The error message is "No such file or directory"

**Solution:**
[You are running the wrong file version for your system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists).

The problem can occur for example if you run your Jenkins installation in a Docker container with Alpine Linux, [since Alpine uses musl libc. The Oracle Java binaries only run on glibc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147882/1838233)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the Oracle JDK autoinstall didn't really do anything on my system (confirmed by checking Jenkins' system properties for Java). I found that openjdk 1.8 happen to already be on that container, so I manually pointed JAVA_HOME to that instead of relying on the Oracle JDK autoinstall.

Comment: I face the same issue with you. So now you just use OpenJDK, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed the project JDK setting to system, my build progressed past this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A really good answer would explain where that setting is (I'm guessing it's in Jenkins?) and why changing that particular setting worked.