# Jenkins config JDK for project and maven build always get error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 2.107.2

How to configure the Jenkins project to use the custom JDK with Maven?

I have added JDK in the Global Tool Configuration and Maven with automatically install. I add two version of JDK.

Then I create a maven project by specifying one of the JDK and one of Maven. But I always get the error of `mvn` cannot find the `java` as JDKfollows:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-        3.5.3/bin/mvn package
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn: exec: line 199:         
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8-172/bin/java: not found
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Then I try a lot of methods, only the system OpenJDK is work (chose JDK with System on the Jenkins project)

I also try

1. config JAVA_HOME to the installed JDK
2. config Tool Path

I also check the mvn and java in the Jenkins master(I use Docker to run the Jenkins), the JAVA_HOME is the OpenJDK and the mvn is not set.

Comment: is mvn -v showing correctly ?.. in MVN -V command JAVA_HOME is pointing the JRE folder like this :- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre

Comment: because I use the docker, so I run `mvn -v` in the bin/bash not work (exec -it xxx /bin/bash).

Comment: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -v

    Apache Maven 3.3.9 
    (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11 -10T16:41:47+00:00)
    Maven home: 
  
  /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.3.9
    Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64", arch: 
 "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: if I run mvn with auto install path, the Java Home will display the system jre version

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737624/jenkins-blue-ocean-maven-doesnt-see-java/