# How to use JDK 11 from host system in containerized Jenkins to build Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jenkins, java-11

I have `jenkinsci/blueocean:latest` used in my `docker-compose.yml` it does not support however JDK 11 is installed at the host system of docker.

Now this dockerized Jenkins is based on JDK 8, but I want to use 11 for my project builds using Spring Boot 2.

**How can one use the JDK 11 installed at the host system while building jobs on dockerized jenkins?**

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: Why can't you use jenkins image with jdk11 installed?

Comment: @michalk I want the `blueocean edition`. They claim here: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/12/14/java11-preview-availability/ That the `jenkins4eval/blueocean-platform-support` is experimental.

Comment: @michalk Secondly I want to be able to update the jdk version with my system package manager so that I do not have to install new image everytime I want to update jdk version - afraid of errors then.

Comment: @michalk do you mean `jenkins/jenkins:jdk11`? Can this use `blueocean`? Is it stable and have jdk11 installed for pipeline jobs?

Answer (score 0):

The java for linux depends on glibc, the docker image `jenkinsci/blueocean:latest` uses alpine and alpine uses MUSL as a standard C library.

To use java in alpine images, have some tricks, but is not easy. Do you have some alternatives do prepare docker image. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147371/docker-alpine-oracle-java-cannot-find-java/45147882#45147882) fro more info.

To work, do you have to use another imagem from jenkins what don't use alpine. 
See examples bellow

```
version: '3'

services:
  blueocean:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jdk-11.0.2:/opt/jdk11-glibc # doens't work
      - ./jdk-13-ea-musl:/opt/jdk13-musl # work

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jdk-11.0.2:/opt/jdk11-glibc # work
      - ./jdk-13-ea-musl:/opt/jdk13-musl # doens't work

  jenkins-alpine:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:alpine
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jdk-11.0.2:/opt/jdk11-glibc # doens't work
      - ./jdk-13-ea-musl:/opt/jdk13-musl # work

  # alternatively, you can use the jenkins version with jdk11 and install blueocean
  jenkins-jdk11:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:jdk11
    ports:
      - 8083:8080
```

You want to keep the settings when updating the jenkins, do you have to externalise volume `/var/jenkins_home`.

Comment: I want to build SpringBoot2 proejct with JDK11 I don't need Jenkins to run on JDK11. Question is how to enable Jenkins to use JDK11 to build my project?

Comment: My comment was not to run the jenkins with jdk11 but rather how to map the jdk11 of your host machine, after mapping you should add the jdk going in the tool settings and adding the jdk in the folder mapped as a volume, but even mapping a jdk external, it does not work because the jenkinsci/blueocean:latest container uses alpine as the base image, so I used the jdk13 version for alpine to exemplify do you need a specific jdk version to MUSL.
I added as an alternative to running jenkins with jdk 11 directly.
Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ok so if I want to use the first option I assume that `jdk-13-ea-musl` will work for jdk11 Spring boot 2 build? If so I would have to install the jdk13 first on my host system, or just place the binary in `./jdk-13-ea-musl` ?

Comment: I tested with a simple spring-boot app and works fine, but, you have to test with your app to confirm.

Comment: Ok my app needs to be stable not `ea` status. So if I choose the most stable last case with `jenkins/jenkins:jdk11` I will simplu configure jenkins to `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11`

Comment: I suggest you use a jdk stable version, in this case you have to use another image from jenkins. `jenkins/jenkins:latest` or `jenkins/jenkins:lts`

Comment: But `jenkns:latest` and `jenkins:lts` does not support `jdk11`?

Comment: No, both run with JDK8, but you can add another JDK (6, 7, 11, ...) to run you build

Comment: How can I add the JDK 11? The way that you have shown in your answer or is there some other way?