# Installing Oracle Java 11 on Alpine Linux with Docker

Tags: java, docker, java-11, alpine-linux

I am trying to configure Alpine with Oracle JDK.  I have downloaded the JDK and am copying it into my image and using it there.

When I run `which java` it reports back the correct path `/jdk-11.0.10/bin/java` but when I try to run any `java` command it says it is not found.

I tried to reference some info from

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Oracle_Java

WRT how to do this but I'm not having any luck.

Any input would be appreciated!

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add freetype fontconfig paxctl
COPY jdk-11.0.10_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /

RUN tar -xf jdk-11.0.10_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

ENV JAVA_HOME /jdk-11.0.10
ENV PATH ${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
CMD echo ${PATH}
CMD echo which java
RUN paxctl -c java
RUN paxctl -m java
RUN paxctl -c javac
RUN paxctl -m javac
CMD java -version
```

Comment: How do you run these java commands?

Comment: This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147371/docker-alpine-oracle-java-cannot-find-java/45147882).

Comment: The question is why? OracleJDK 11 and OpenJDK 11 are as far as I know identical. Oracle JDK has just the disadvantage that you have to pay for it in a lot of usage scenarios.

Comment: Open JDK is not supported by the Java Application I am running - that is why I have to use Oracle.

Comment: OpenJDK 11 has a community Alpine (musl-libc) port. Oracle JDK 11 is linked against glibc, the GNU C library, like most Linux software, which is not compatible with musl-libc in many aspects. Therefore, you can't run Java builds compiled for a glibc distro (Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora etc.) on vanilla Alpine. The "not found" error when trying to run `java` is actually a dynamic link failure.

Comment: stumbled upon this while trying out elasticsearch 7.16.3 in alpine3.11.. it works fine w/ `openjdk8-jre` but if I try `openjdk9-jre` or even 10, 11. So I'm stuck with
```/usr/src/app # java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.17.1) (Alpine 8.275.01-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
``` .. if I get rid of all `COPY` commands in my Dockerfile it works again. I am thinking it has something to do with this - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8165852 . So I wanted to try oracle jdk, if it has the issue.

Comment: Try the `gcompat` package for glibc compatibility, in some cases it helps.