# Failed to get jdk (jdk-8u301-linux-x64.tar.gz) on alpine:3.8

Tags: docker, java-8, dockerfile

I'm trying to build the image which was built in the past but failing this time as it is failing to download Oracle JDK, it downloads the tar with just a 4 KB file.

I have referred this [Docker alpine + oracle java: cannot find java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147371/docker-alpine-oracle-java-cannot-find-java) already and tried with the latest version of glibc but no luck.

I'm though able to install the lower version than jdk-8u201.

Any suggestion is appreciated! I have to go with alpine:3.8 only.

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk upgrade --update && \
    apk add --update curl ca-certificates bash && \
    for pkg in glibc-2.23-r1 glibc-bin-2.23-r1 glibc-i18n-2.23-r1; do curl -sSL https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r1/${pkg}.apk -o /tmp/${pkg}.apk; done && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/*.apk && \
    rm -v /tmp/*.apk && \
    mkdir -p /opt/springboot/apps/ && \
    ( /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef --force --inputfile POSIX --charmap UTF-8 C.UTF-8 || true ) && \
    echo "export LANG=C.UTF-8" > /etc/profile.d/locale.sh && \
    /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib && \
    curl -jksSLH "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -o /tmp/java.tar.gz \
    https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    gunzip /tmp/java.tar.gz
```

Comment: What _does_ it download?  Are there any error messages you get?  (Try running the `curl` command from the host, outside of Docker, and unpacking the tar file there.)

Comment: It downloads the tar file just with 4KB and that's something I figured out while I was running the command (from Dockerfile) one after another on alpine image.

Comment: Is it a shell script?  An error page?  A statically-linked binary that downloads the installer?  4096 null bytes?

Comment: It's a Dockerfile, and yes 4096 null bytes.