# Dockerfile combining MAVEN, JAVA and COMPOSE

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to create a DOCKER container to be used by my gitlab-runner in order to compile/deploy my Quarkus microservices.
Here is what I've done :

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk as JDK

FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-11 as MAVEN

FROM docker/compose

ENV LANG='fr_FR.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='fr_FR:fr'

LABEL description="Runner for compiling/deploying my QUARKUS services " \
      version="${VERSION}"

COPY --from=JDK /usr/local/openjdk-11 /usr/local/openjdk-11
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11
RUN { echo '#/bin/sh'; echo 'echo "$JAVA_HOME"'; } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ] # backwards compatibility
ENV PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

COPY --from=MAVEN /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY --from=MAVEN /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven
RUN ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
ENV MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG="$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

RUN echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11'>/root/env \
    && echo 'MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven'>>/root/env \
    && echo 'MAVEN_CONFIG="$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"'>> /root/env \
    && chmod +x /root/env\
    && source /root/env

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mvn"]
```

It's inspired by Dockerfiles in docker hub ...
It doesn't work : in gitlab pipeline it says :[image]
So I tried some commands :
`docker run --rm runner4geo3d:1.0 echo $JAVA_HOME` it says nothing => it explains why runner fails ...
But I did set these variables !
and more, when I inspect :

```
docker inspect runnerxxx:1.0
[
    {
(...)
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11",
                "MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven",
                "MAVEN_CONFIG=/root/.m2"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"mvn\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:7ab7026055a9a6af295a884f9eee926bbb4cdb6a5102f0c07756e69e4bf95126",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "description": "Runner for compiling/deploying QUARKUS services ",
                "version": ""
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11",
                "MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven",
                "MAVEN_CONFIG=/root/.m2"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mvn"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:7ab7026055a9a6af295a884f9eee926bbb4cdb6a5102f0c07756e69e4bf95126",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "description": "Runner for compiling/deploying QUARKUS services ",
                "version": ""
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 434176309,
        "VirtualSize": 434176309,
        (..)
```

Any idea why these variables aren't set ? What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Funny : `docker run --rm --env JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/openjdk-11" runner:1.0 echo $JAVA_HOME` gives nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Docker alpine + oracle java: cannot find java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147371/docker-alpine-oracle-java-cannot-find-java/45147882) I found why java was not found ... The `FROM docker/compose` instruction in the Dockerfile is about an image built on musl lib (alpine) => no java is possible with it (easily).
I changed it with `docker/compose:debian-1.29.2` and then it finds java :)